# Downloading file using wget directly into an EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, wget

I am trying to download a zip file using wget directly from my EC2 instance. The command actually works and a file is downloaded, however it is a fraction of the size it is supposed to be (supposed to be 7 GB and the file downloaded is 14K) and unzip commands are not working.

Any ideas? I'd prefer not to download the file to my local computer and then use scp (although if I have to I guess that is what I'll do)

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, the website requires authentication before downloading the file, so I believe I just need to add login credentials as parameters in the wget command:

```
wget --user=user --password=password
```